# ways in which the spring cloud task post the response back to the caller

Tags: spring, cloud, spring-cloud-task

I created a spring cloud task to create a new user in my db,is there any way to post the successfull response message back to my rest service ?,from which i invoked this task.

Answer (score 0):

You could control the desired behavior of the `spring-cloud-task` application's lifecycle with the [exit codes](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#features-lifecycle-exit-codes), but there's no OOTB support to register an automatic callback routine.

In your custom task application, after the DB persistence, you could make a REST call to let the client application update its state.

Alternatively, if you'd like to do this in an asynchronous manner, you could consider writing the outcome to a topic/queue backed by messaging middleware of choice and then have your REST application listen and consume the messages from the broker for relevant updates.